# Handling directory error with submitted patch

Tags: 8, version-control

1. Drupal 8.x
2. MAC OSX +
3. Vagrant 2.2.0

How can I trace/define a directory error while trying to apply a Drupal.org patch?

I have a patch submitted to a Drupal project module, and while trying to apply the patch locally I get this error:

```
Checking patch src/Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php...
error: src/Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php: already exists in
working directory
Checking patch src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php...
```

I am applying the patch via [cweagans/composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) and `composer install` in the Drupal root directory after `vagrant ssh`. (`git apply -v [patchname.patch]` returns the same error)

The patch is trying to do two things, change a directory name from `form` to `Form` (case change), as well as update some code in one of the modules files (src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php).

Issue link if needed: https://www.drupal.org/project/user_menu_avatar/issues/3024739

---

**composer.json**:

```
    {
        "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
        "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
        "type": "project",
        "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "role": ""
            }
        ],
        "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "composer",
                "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
            }
        ],
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.6",
            "composer/installers": "^1.2",
            "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
            "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
            "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
            "drupal/core": "^8.6.0",
            "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
            "drupal/user_menu_avatar": "^2.0",
            "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
            "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
            "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
            "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
            "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.6.0"
        },
        "conflict": {
            "drupal/drupal": "*"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true,
        "config": {
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
            ],
            "files": ["load.environment.php"]
        },
        "scripts": {
            "pre-install-cmd": [
                "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
            ],
            "pre-update-cmd": [
                "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
            ],
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
            ]
        },
        "extra": {
            "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
            "patches-file": "./composer.patches.json",
            "patchLevel": {
                "drupal/core": "-p2"
            },
            "installer-paths": {
                "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
                "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
                "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
                "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
                "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
                "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
            },
            "drupal-scaffold": {
                "initial": {
                    ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                    ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**composer.patches.json**:

```
{
  "patches": {
    "drupal/user_menu_avatar": {
      "Config form page returns WSOD in some instances": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-09/user_menu_avatar-settings_form-3024739-2.patch"
    }
  }
}
```

---

`composer install --verbose`:

```
    vagrant@vanilla:/var/www/drupal$ composer install --verbose
    Gathering patches from patch file.
    Removing package drupal/user_menu_avatar so that it can be re-installed and re-patched.
      - Removing drupal/user_menu_avatar (2.0.0)
    Deleting web/modules/contrib/user_menu_avatar - deleted
    > pre-install-cmd: DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
    Dependency resolution completed in 0.002 seconds
    Analyzed 328 packages to resolve dependencies
    Analyzed 1219 rules to resolve dependencies
    Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
    Installs: drupal/user_menu_avatar:2.0.0
    Gathering patches from patch file.
    Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
    Found 1 patches for drupal/user_menu_avatar.
      - Installing drupal/user_menu_avatar (2.0.0): Loading from cache
     Extracting archive  - Applying patches for drupal/user_menu_avatar
        https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-09/user_menu_avatar-settings_form-3024739-2.patch (Config form page returns WSOD in some instances)
    patch '-p1' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'web/modules/contrib/user_menu_avatar' < '/tmp/5c5da64c3c199.patch'
    The next patch would create the file src/Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php,
    which already exists!
      Assume -R? [n] 

    Apply anyway? [n] 

    Skipping patch.

    1 out of 1 hunk ignored

    patching file src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php

    patch '-p0' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'web/modules/contrib/user_menu_avatar' < '/tmp/5c5da64c3c199.patch'
    patching file b/src/Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php

    patching file b/src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php

    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!
      Assume -R? [n] 

    Apply anyway? [n] 

    Skipping patch.

    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
     -- saving rejects to file b/src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php.rej

    patch '-p2' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'web/modules/contrib/user_menu_avatar' < '/tmp/5c5da64c3c199.patch'
    patching file Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php

    patching file form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php

    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!
      Assume -R? [n] 

    Apply anyway? [n] 

    Skipping patch.

    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
     -- saving rejects to file form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php.rej

    patch '-p4' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'web/modules/contrib/user_menu_avatar' < '/tmp/5c5da64c3c199.patch'
    can't find file to patch at input line 6

    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

    The text leading up to this was:
    --------------------------

    |diff --git a/src/Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php b/src/Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php
    |new file mode 100644
    |index 0000000..19e3434
    |--- /dev/null
    |+++ b/src/Form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php
    --------------------------

    File to patch: 

    Skip this patch? [y] 

    Skipping patch.

    1 out of 1 hunk ignored

    can't find file to patch at input line 219

    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

    The text leading up to this was:
    --------------------------

    |diff --git a/src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php b/src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php
    |index c019638..19e3434 100644
    |--- a/src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php
    |+++ b/src/form/UserMenuAvatarConfigurationForm.php
    --------------------------

    File to patch: 

    Skip this patch? [y] 

    Skipping patch.

    1 out of 1 hunk ignored

       Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-09/user_menu_avatar-settings_form-3024739-2.patch

      [Exception]                                                                                                                                                          
      Cannot apply patch Config form page returns WSOD in some instances (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-09/user_menu_avatar-settings_form-3024739-2.patch)!
```

**Note: I am now doing this work on a brand new machine. New OS, new installs of composer, Drupal, git, etc...*

**Note: I have had success downloading the patch as a file in the Drupal root directory, updating my `composer.patches.json`, and running composer install. Then, I do not get the directory issue. However the directory does not get changed from `form` to `Form`. Though the patch completes and updates the module file contents.*

Comment: **How** exactly are you trying to apply the patch?

Comment: This should not be an issue with Composer. It sounds like you have a dirty working directory (where that module is)? Also, was the file rename done as a delete/add or as a git rename?

Comment: The command is from the "version control" tab of the Drupal project: `git apply -v [patchname.patch]`. As for composer, that is something I could test. I can spin up another Drupal install. For the filename, it has remained the same, except the directory change... but it is a git a/b change in the patch.

Comment: I assumed you were applying patches with Composer

Comment: This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21735779/9302793. Talks about Git folder names and case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Don't apply patches like that anymore. Let Composer handle this. I hope you already are managing your site with Composer. Then you need to require [`cweagans/composer-patches`](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) first.

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

And then it's just a new `"patches"` array in your `composer.json` providing patches like so:

```
    "patches": {
        "drupal/user_menu_avatar": {
            "Config form page do not work": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-09/user_menu_avatar-settings_form-3024739-2.patch"
        },
        "drupal/foobar": {
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-02/1234567.patch"
        }
    }
```

Finally run `composer install` again, done.

Comment: The composer.json should be manually updated/edited?

Comment: @Prestosaurus – In that case, yes. To add the patches. Alternatively you could make use of another nice package: https://github.com/szeidler/composer-patches-cli

Comment: I would agree that composer is the way to go, however, I am still getting the same error. Reject files are created in new directories `b` and `Form` in the module root. Looks like I may have an issue still to resolve. I've added the verbose output above from composer install.

Comment: Delete the module manually and then re add it with composer require ...

Comment: @Prestosaurus – What Kevin says. Seems your working tree is unclean. Readd everything. Maybe `"discard-changes": true` in the `"config"` array of your `composer.json` also helps.

Comment: Hmmm... brand new vagrant, Drupal install, and pull of module. nothing else installed. Still getting the same errors when trying to use composer to install the patch. one error I see after composer first fails, then tries to use git apply is `fatal: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 4 leading pathname components (line 6)`. But it is still around the file already exists. Trying to find related questions, any thoughts would be appreciated. Can I provide any other testing results to help? I've also added `"discard-changes": true` to `config.yml`.

Comment: @Prestosaurus – And what happens when you run `rm -rf vendor && rm composer.lock && composer clearcache && composer install`?

Comment: Just ran the commands: cleared cache, downloaded packages, installed Drupal core, loaded repositories, installed dependencies, tried applying the patch with the message `Cannot apply patch Config form page do not work (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-09/user_menu_avatar-settings_form-3024739-2.patch)!`. This is with a `composer.patches.yml` file and `"patches-file": "./composer.patches.json"` in the extra array of the `config.yml`.